# Batch variable not incrementing!

Tags: batch-file

```
SET /a _count = 1

set /p drive=Please type drive name[C/D/E/F/..]?: 
echo Creating Directory %drive%:\AKI_Data_Feeds
mkdir %drive%:\AKI_Data_Feeds

for /f %%a in (companyList.txt) do (
echo Creating Directory %drive%:\AKI_Data_Feeds\%%a
mkdir %drive%:\AKI_Data_Feeds\%%a

for /f %%b in (branch1.txt) do (
echo Creating Directory %drive%:\AKI_Data_Feeds\%%a\%%b
mkdir %drive%:\AKI_Data_Feeds\%%a\%%b


if "%_count%"=="1" (

for /f %%c in (branch1_1.txt) do (
echo Creating Directory %drive%:\AKI_Data_Feeds\%%a\%%b\%%c
mkdir %drive%:\AKI_Data_Feeds\%%a\%%b\%%c

for /f %%e in (branch2.txt) do (
echo Creating Directory %drive%:\AKI_Data_Feeds\%%a\%%b\%%c\%%e
mkdir %drive%:\AKI_Data_Feeds\%%a\%%b\%%c\%%e
)

)

SET /a _count +=1
echo %_count%

)
if "%_count%"=="2" (
for /f %%d in (branch1_2.txt) do (
echo Creating Directory %drive%:\AKI_Data_Feeds\%%a\%%b\%%d
mkdir %drive%:\AKI_Data_Feeds\%%a\%%b\%%d

for /f %%e in (branch2.txt) do (
echo Creating Directory %drive%:\AKI_Data_Feeds\%%a\%%b\%%c\%%e
mkdir %drive%:\AKI_Data_Feeds\%%a\%%b\%%c\%%e
)

)

SET /a _count +=1

)

)
)

echo Successfully created.
pause
```

_count is not getting incremented

Comment: What `command.com`/`cmd` is this?

Comment: i am running this in a .bat file

Comment: ...on MS-DOS 3.3, Windows XP, Windows 98, FreeDos.. ?

Comment: Indenting blocks could be nice ...

Answer (score 6):

You need the delayed expansion to solve this.
As all percent variables expands while a block is parsed, their values seems to be unchanged.

With delayed expansion the variables are expanded at execution time.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set count=0
(
   set /a count+=1
   echo %count% fails
   echo !count! works
)
```

Comment: Any reference on the ! vs % usage ?